# On Navigation Drawer item click Popup Window

Tags: android

[image]

I want to develop a navigation drawer and `onNavItemClick` i want to show a popup window attached to particullar nav Item (nav drawer must remain open)
If anyone has implemented this please provide a link.

Here is my code snippet.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    switch(position)
    {

        case 0:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.history);
            fragment_ride_history = new ListView(this);
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    fragment_ride_history,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(newBitmapDrawable());
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(new LinearLayout(this), Gravity.END, 10, 10);
            popupWindow.update(50, 50, 1500, 900);
            popupWindow.setContentView(fragment_ride_history);
            // this is to call webservice and append the data on listview
            getData(1);
            fragment_ride_history.setOnScrollListener(new 
            break;
   }
}
```

Comment: popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorview, 0, 0, Gravity.RIGHT);

Comment: A bit of. I am looking for exactly a view which is shown in my image link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem for display "popupWindow" on "onNavigationDrawerItemSelected"

I think the problem on "setBackgroundDrawable" because your code work with me i just remove `setBackgroundDrawable`
and I added

```
fragment_ride_history.setBackgroundColor
```

test if first without call webservice

for webservice try to call it from AsyncTask or you can use volley lib and show popupwindow at response of call to dont display empty listview.

Comment: Yes it is ok just for displaying pop-up window but I am looking for exactly the view which is in my image link.thnx

Comment: you need to dont close navigationDrawer and update 
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(new LinearLayout(this), Gravity.END, 10, 10);
            popupWindow.update(50, 50, 1500, 900); remove new LinearLayout(this) to DrawerLayout and update the value for x, y, height

Comment: Yes and it should attached to drawer item like in expandable view.